# casting a private members type in a class

Tags: typescript, class, generics, casting

I'm writing a simple typescript port of Rust's [Result](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) enum using a class

```js
class Result<T, E> {
  private value: T | E;
  private _ok: boolean;

  private constructor(f: () => T) {
    try {
      this.value = f();
      this._ok = true;
    } catch (e) {
      this.value = e as E;
      this._ok = false;
    }
  }

  static from<T, E>(f: () => T) {
    return new Result<T, E>(f);
  }

  is_ok(): this['value'] is T {
    return this._ok;
  }

  unwrap(): T {
    if (this.is_ok()) return this.value as T;
    throw new Error("some error");
  }
}
```

I want to assert that the value property is T when is_ok returns true, else it is E which is_ok is false meaning the value is an error.

But using `this['value']` makes typescript throw an error saying private values cannot be accessed, [image]

again using `this is { value: T }` throws different error
[image]
How do i solve this? its possible to just cast `value as T` in every method but it wouldnt solve it on the user end and there should be a more smorter way i believe. Any help is appreciated

Comment: [Please replace images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: You can't access easily manipulate `private` properties via the type system.  Either make it `public`, or try to say the same thing in a different way perhaps as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mL3yKN).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: that actually works for me, tho i dont understand whats it doing. hovering over it ts is infering value as `T | (T & E)` what does that mean?

Comment: It is narrowing from `Result<T, E>` to `Result<T, E> & Result<T, never>`; sometimes user defined type guard functions use intersections to narrow (if the compiler isn't totally sure that the narrowed type is a subtype of the original type, it will use an intersection), and so `value` is `(T | E) & (T | never)` which reduces to `(T | E) & T` which reduces to `(T & T) | (E & T)` which reduces to `T | (E & T)`. This is equivalent to `T`, but the compiler doesn't aggressively reduce that.  Does that make sense?  I will write up a full answer when I get a chance.